# Flat JSON to hierarchy with repeated nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, flatten

I am building a hierarchical object structure from a flat one. Everything has worked fine so far, but I have a problem with items who share the same parent id. For example:

```
{
   'id': 9,
   'parentid': 7
 }, {
   'id': 9,
   'parentid': 8
 }, {
   'id': 10,
   'parentid': 9
 }
```

To my understanding, the correct thing is that the item with id 9, appears both under parent 7, and parent 8. And at the same time, the item with id 10 appears under both instances of id 9. So, I basically want this:

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "parentid": 1,
    "children": [
     {
      "id": 9,
      "parentid": 7,
      "children": [
       {
        "id": 10,
        "parentid": 9,
        "children": []
       },
{
    "id": 8,
    "parentid": 1,
    "children": [
     {
      "id": 9,
      "parentid": 8,
      "children": [
       {
        "id": 10,
        "parentid": 9,
        "children": []
       }
```

But I am getting this instead. When an id has been allocated once, possible new appearances of that id are ignored.

```
  {
    "id": 8,
    "parentid": 1,
    "children": [
     {
      "id": 9,
      "parentid": 8,
      "children": [
       {
        "id": 10,
        "parentid": 9,
        "children": []
       }
```

This is the function I am using:

```
 function unflatten(arr) {
   var tree = [],
     mappedArr = {},
     arrElem,
     mappedElem;

   // First map the nodes of the array to an object -> create a hash table.
   for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
     arrElem = arr[i];
     mappedArr[arrElem.id] = arrElem;
     mappedArr[arrElem.id]['children'] = [];
   }


   for (var id in mappedArr) {
     if (mappedArr.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
       mappedElem = mappedArr[id];
       // If the element is not at the root level, add it to its parent array of children.
       if (mappedElem.parentid) {
         mappedArr[mappedElem['parentid']]['children'].push(mappedElem);
       }
       // If the element is at the root level, add it to first level elements array.
       else {
         tree.push(mappedElem);
       }
     }
   }
   return tree;
 }

 var tree = unflatten(arr);
```

I don´t understand what is needed to consider all the appearances of the id, not only the first time. Which idea should I research further?

Comment: There is no JSON in this question...

Comment: It is counter-intuitive to have an object id, and yet want to have a version of that object with one parent, and another with another parent. In that case it is *not* and identifier. You should consider creating a property `parentIds` in plural and assign it an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is counter-intuitive to have an object ***id***, and yet want to have a version of that object with one value for *parentid*, and another with another value for *parentid*. Logically, an *id* should identify one object, and one object can not have two different values for the same property at the same time.

Note how this makes your code go wrong in this line:

```
mappedArr[arrElem.id] = arrElem;
```

As the same *id* occurs multiple times, you *overwrite* the same entry with whatever is the last object (version) you assign here, losing the previous one(s) that had other values for *parentid*.

You should consider creating a property *parentIds*, in plural, and assign it an array of parent *id* values. That way you can maintain a situation where really one object has multiple parents.

Note that a graph where nodes can not only have multiple children, but also have multiple parents, is not a tree (your variable name is thus misleading), but a (directed) graph.

Starting with your code, I modified it to this:

```js
function unflatten(arr) {
    var node,
        graph = [], // it is not a tree
        mapped = [];
    
    // 1. combine nodes with the same id:
    arr.forEach( function (node) {
        (mapped[node.id] || (mapped[node.id] = {
            id: node.id,
            parentIds: [],
            children: []
        })).parentIds.push(node.parentid);
    });
    
    // 2. assign children:
    mapped.forEach(function (node) {
        // Add as child to each of the parents 
        node.parentIds.forEach(function (parentid) {
            if (mapped[parentid]) {
                mapped[parentid]['children'].push(node);
            } else {
                // If parent does not exist as node, create it at the root level, 
                // and add it to first level elements array.
                graph.push(mapped[parentid] = {
                    id: parentid,
                    parentids: [],
                    children: [node]
                });
            }
        });
    });
    return graph;
}
// Sample data
var arr = [{
   'id': 9,
   'parentid': 7
}, {
   'id': 9,
   'parentid': 8
}, {
   'id': 10,
   'parentid': 9
}];
// Convert:
var graph = unflatten(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(graph, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You are totally right. The issue with the unique id was a bad mistake. Your solution works well in the snippet. I will study it and adapt it for my project. Thanks!